# Constructing SOAP Security Header for wsse:UserToken

Tags: security, authentication, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to manually construct a SOAP request to an Address Validation webservice that requires a SOAP `<Security>` header to be set.   But I can't seem to get it right.  The technology stack I'm using (Salesforce) necessitates me forming the XML myself.

From the WSDL:

```
<s0:Policy s1:Id="derm.service.common.esb.wspolicy.UNT.1">
        <wssp:Identity xmlns:wssp="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy">
            <wssp:SupportedTokens>
                <wssp:SecurityToken TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken">
                <wssp:UsePassword Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-usernametoken-profile-1.0#PasswordText" />
                </wssp:SecurityToken>
            </wssp:SupportedTokens>
        </wssp:Identity>
    </s0:Policy>
```

Full WSDL:  http://pastebin.com/Z5VswYNF

From the documentation linked from the WSDL (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf) I retrieved this example:

```
<wsse:Security>
   <wsse:UsernameToken>
   <wsse:Username>REDACTED_PLAINTEXT_USERNAME</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password>REDACTED_PLAINTEXT_PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Replacing the values with the Username / Password I've been supplied and firing off the sample request from the documentation doesn't work.

Sample request with Security header:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soap="information.qld.gov.au/service/Addressing/ValidationService/2/soap">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
       <wsse:UsernameToken>
       <wsse:Username>REDACTED_PLAINTEXT_USERNAME</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password>REDACTED_PLAINTEXT_PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
       </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<soap:ParseValidAddress>
<soap:addressString>867 Main Street Woolloongabba Queensland</soap:addressString>
<soap:postcodeOption>Include</soap:postcodeOption>
<soap:meshblockOption>Exclude</soap:meshblockOption>
</soap:ParseValidAddress>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Everything I try gets a generic error message

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>The requested operation was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.Your support ID is: REDACTED_SUPPORT_ID</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've also tried the following from elsewhere on stackexchange:

```
  <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="SOAP-ENV">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>oneview</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">oneview123</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am missing the wsse namespace specification in your SOAP message.
You can find it in the link from your text:
"From the documentation linked from the WSDL (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf)"
The value is http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd